# Definition of stability for multistep methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

I am reading *An Introduction to Numerical Analysis* by Atkinson, and I want to make sure that I am correctly interpreting the author's definition of stability for a multistep method. In this context, a multistep method is a method of the form

$$ y_{n+1} = \sum_{j=0}^{p} a_j y_{n-j} + h \sum_{j=-1}^{p} b_j f(x_{n-j},y_{n-j}), \quad n \geq p \qquad (*) $$

for solving the initial value problem $Y'(x) = f(x,Y(x)), \; Y(x_0) = Y_0$, with $f:[x_0,b] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ assumed to be uniformly Lipschitz in its second argument. The $x_n$'s are uniformly spaced nodes in the interval $[x_0,b]$, with step size $h := x_{n+1} - x_n$. The initial values $y_0,\ldots,y_p$ are assumed to be given. On page 394, Atkinson gives the following definition of stability for $(*)$:

> Let $\{y_n:0 \leq n \leq N(h)\}$ be the solution of $(*)$ for some differential equation $Y'(x) = f(x,Y(x)), \; Y(x_0) = Y_0$ for all sufficiently small values of $h$, say $h \leq h_0$. Recall that $N(h)$ denotes the largest subscript $N$ for which $x_N \leq b$. For each $h \leq h_0$, perturb the initial values $y_0,\ldots,y_p$ to new values $z_0,\ldots,z_p$ with
> $$ \max_{0 \leq n \leq p} |y_n - z_n| \leq \epsilon, \quad 0 < h \leq h_0. $$
>
> Note that these initial values are likely to depend on $h$. We say the family of solutions $\{y_n: 0 \leq n \leq N(h) \}$ is *stable* if there is a constant $C$, independent of $h \leq h_0$ and valid for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$, for which
> $$ \max_{0 \leq n \leq N(h)} |y_n - z_n| \leq C \epsilon, \quad 0 < h \leq h_0. $$
>
> Consider all differential equation problems
> $$ Y'(x) = f(x,Y(x)), \quad Y(x_0) = Y_0 $$
> with derivative $f$ continuous and satisfying the Lipschitz condition (6.2.12) [i.e. $f$ is uniformly Lipschitz in its second argument], and suppose the approximating solutions $\{y_n\}$ are all stable. Then we say that $(*)$ is a *stable numerical method.*

**My interpretation.** (To emphasize the dependence of the iterates on the step size $h$, I'll write $y_n(h)$ and $z_n(h)$ for $y_n$ and $z_n$, respectively.)

Let $h_0 > 0$ be fixed. For each $h \in (0,h_0]$ let $\epsilon_0(h),\ldots,\epsilon_p(h) \in \mathbb{R}$ and define $z_n(h) := y_n(h) + \epsilon_n(h)$ for $n=0,1,\ldots,p$. Then define $z_{n}(h)$ for $n > p$ by the recursive equation
$$ z_{n+1}(h) := \sum_{j=0}^{p} a_j z_{n-j}(h) + \sum_{j=-1}^{p} b_j f(x_{n-j}(h),z_{n-j}(h)). $$

The family of numerical solutions

$$ \mathcal{Y}(f,h_0) := \left\{ (y_n(h))_{n=0}^{N(h)}: h \in (0,h_0] \right\}$$

is called *stable* if there exist constants $\epsilon_0 > 0$ and $C \geq 0$ independent of $h$ such that
$$ \max_{0 \leq n \leq p} |\epsilon_n(h)| \leq \epsilon \implies \max_{0 \leq n \leq N(h)} |z_n(h) - y_n(h)| \leq C\epsilon $$
for all $\epsilon \leq \epsilon_0$ and all $h \leq h_0$.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the collection of all functions $f:[x_0,b] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which are continuous and uniformly Lipschitz in their second argument. Then $(*)$ is a *stable numerical method* if the family of solutions $\mathcal{Y}(f,h_0)$ is stable for each $f \in \mathcal{F}$ and each $h_0 > 0$.

**Questions.**

1. Are my interpretations of the stability definitions correct?
2. What does it mean when it says that the perturbations are "likely" to depend on $h$? Should I be thinking of the $\epsilon_n(h)$'s as round-off errors?

---

Edit: Let me make another attempt at stating the definition of stability, after Lutz Lehmann's feedback.

**Attempt 2.** The family of numerical solutions
$$ \Big\{ \big((y_n(h) \big)_{n=0}^{N(h)}: h > 0 \Big\}$$
is *stable* if there exist constants $\epsilon_0 >0, h_0 > 0$ and $C \geq 0$ such that, if $0 < h \leq h_0$ and $0 < \epsilon \leq \epsilon_0$ and $z_0,\ldots,z_p \in \mathbb{R}$, the following implication holds:
$$ \max_{0 \leq n \leq p} |y_n(h) - z_n| \leq \epsilon \implies \max_{0 \leq n \leq N(h)} |y_n(h) - z_n(h)| \leq C \epsilon.  $$

Is this version correct?

Answer (score 1):

@2. Of course the starter points $y_0,...,y_p$ from the exact solution will depend on $h$, as their location $x_n(h)=x_0+hn$ depends on $h$. Often the practically used starter points $z_0,...,z_p$ will be computed with a Runge-Kutta method in fixed-step mode. The deviations $\epsilon_n(h)$ thus depend on step size and method. The floating-point error is usually not considered in these theoretical explorations.

@1. You have somewhat restricted the definition, as in the definition the starter values are arbitrary in a ball around the exact values, while your interpretation restricts them to a path. Considering all paths makes the admissible set of perturbations unnecessarily larger, just considering the balls of radius $\epsilon$ appears more simple.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your point regarding 2) makes sense. I'm confused on your point regarding 1), specifically what you mean by a "path". 

How exactly should I change the line "$\max_{0 \leq n \leq p} |\epsilon_n(h)| \leq \epsilon \implies ...$" to make my definition correct?

Comment: In my definition, the implication $\max_{0 \leq n \leq p} |\epsilon_n(h)| \leq \epsilon \implies ...$" could be rephrased as $(\epsilon_0(h),\ldots,\epsilon_p(h)) \in B_{\epsilon}(0,\ldots,0)$, where the ball is defined in terms of the $\infty$-norm, so I don't see why this is considered a "path"...

Comment: Because that notation suggests that you get for each $h$ only one value or case. And it makes sense for any fixed starter method. But the definition is somewhat chaotic, it tries to be too general too early. One should start with getting the global error for fixed $h$ and $\epsilon$ and then demand that the constant $C$ be independent of $h$ and $\epsilon$. "For each $h≤h_0$, perturb ..." should not make $h$ variable in this place. One could say "With the fixed $h≤h_0$ ..." or similar, or do not mention $h$ there at all.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by "that notation suggests that you get for each $h$ only one value or case." Are you saying that the perturbation $z_n(h) - y_n(h)$ need not be *solely determined* by $h$? 
I have edited my post and made another attempt to paraphrase the definition of stability. Is my new definition correct?

Comment: By the intention of the definition, the first $p$ values of the $z$ sequence are random, within the stated boundaries. The defining inequality has to hold for all these random situations. Using functional notation suggests a less random situation, a structure that is not present in the definition. In my impression it makes the property stronger, more restrictive than necessary. You indicate that this functional interpretation is not intended, that this notation is just a reminder for the step size. My doubt is that this nonconventional use of standard notation is useful here.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your point:  I edited my new definition to remove the functional notation for the initial values $z_0,\ldots,z_p$. Is the definition correct now?